# LEGO Power Function PF 2.0 specification

Tags: powered-up

Does anyone have the new Power Function 2.0 specification or pin out?

Comment: I don't think an official one has been released, but there are some people who have looked into reverse engineering it. Here's one example I found: https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/162288-powered-up-a-tear-down/

Comment: Why is this tagged with powered-up, are we not confusing power functions with powered up here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for in terms of a spec, but here's the pinout from the [Eurobricks thread](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/162288-powered-up-a-tear-down/) mentioned by Alexander O'Mara with some help from [this post](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/162288-powered-up-a-tear-down/&do=findComment&comment=3009591):

```
Pin 1 - Motor
Pin 2 - Motor
Pin 3 - GND (0v)
Pin 4 - VCC (3.3v)
Pin 5 - ID 1 (UART TX for active devices)
Pin 6 - ID 2 (UART RX for active devices)
```

The basic spec for motors is that they are given continuous 3.3V power on pins 3 and 4, voltages to drive the motor on pins 1 and 2, and pins 5 and 6 are used to identify the type of motor that is attached. For the basic motors, I believe that this is simply a known resistance between pins 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

LPF2 is also known as Powered Up - [ref](https://brickarchitect.com/powered-up/).

The Bluetooth hub is documented: https://github.com/lego/lego-ble-wireless-protocol-docs . This carries a large `gh-pages` branch & corresponding web site.

Philo also [has useful information](https://www.philohome.com/wedo2reverse/wedo2.htm).

*This doesn't answer the original question but I believe anyone searching for info will benefit from the connection.*