# Power Function 2.0 Pin out

Tags: powered-up

Does anyone have the pin out spec for Power Functions 2.0?
Have tried Google and Lego Ed for answers
Is there a source for the connector and receptacle? 
I could not find any data on the connector

Comment: This feels very similar to what you asked about in you last question: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10364/lego-power-function-pf-2-0-specification Did you accidentally ask this twice, or am I not understanding the difference between the two questions?

Comment: I posted it first to the Power-Funcitons section, but on further review of the entries, i would like to post it on the Powered-up tag, as most responses seem to be there rather than a Power-Functions PF2.0 which does not exist as a tag.

Comment: That makes sense. I've retagged your other question as powered-up, and I'll mark this one as a duplicate.